# Mysqli - How to build the Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I try to request my Database so i will get like in Facebook a News Feed (newest Posts) on the Home Site.

I have a Table with Friends
- userid1 - userid2- accepted
So if accepted == 1 they are Friends ... 
[image]

I already tried to Request first the Friends and then get the Posts... Wrong way cause at least they shown it in the Right way with ordered by timestamp... 
But in blocks for each friend... 
not ordered only by Timestamp ...

```
SELECT * FROM friends
WHERE user1='$ownid' or user2='$ownid'
AND accepted='1'
```

My Post table:
 
Userid- from_user_id- timestamp- text 
[image]

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE from_user='$friendsuserid'
ORDER BY RAND() , timestamp desc
```

So my Question,
What is the exact query to get fast all post from my Friends and order them  by timestamp ?

Means-> Check whos friedn-> getPosts -> order by Timestamp 
and all this in 1 Query.... ?

Thanks for every Answer.

Comment: *"What is the exact query to get fast all post"* - is "fast" the operative keyword here? If so, make sure your db is properly indexed.

Comment: AND has higher precedence than OR, so you need to specify the order in parentheses (otherwise it will include lines where `user1=$ownid` regardless of whether its accepted or not.

Comment: Ohh... can you add a example ? Cause iam at this Point more then Confused :/

Comment: @Fred-ii- i search the query .. my Db is indexed by id if you mean this.

Comment: And i know that theres a way to add Mutiple Request in one query ?

Comment: @riv no its correct i guess. Its possible that it is accepted and that one of the ids are my... 
In the following Lines which u cant see here there is a if else ... 
if xxx== my id then...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p INNER JOIN friends f ON
  ((p.from_user=f.user1 OR p.from_user=f.user2) AND (f.user1='$ownid' OR f.user2='$ownid') AND f.accepted) 
  WHERE p.from_user!='$ownid' ORDER BY p.posted_time DESC
```

Comment: Yes this works and brings up the more or less the same as my difficult one :D ... 
But how can i shuffle this posts now and make them Random ? 
      SELECT * FROM posts p INNER JOIN friends f ON
  ((p.from_user=f.user1 OR p.from_user=f.user2) AND (f.user1='$ownid' OR f.user2='$ownid') AND f.accepted) 
    WHERE p.from_user!='$ownid' ORDER BY p.posted_time, by p.BY RAND()

Comment: I thought you wanted them sorted by timestamp? Yeah you could just `ORDER BY RAND()` I guess. Or if you want the last 20 posts (by date), shuffled in random order, you would have to order by timestamp, then limit, then order by rand. Or just shuffle them in PHP. However, I'm not sure how this whole thing would perform when your database grows very large.